# how do i make a python program check if a there is a letter from a string in a string

Tags: python

I am trying to make the python program check if at least one letter is in a string?

```
import string

s = ('hello')

if string.ascii_lowercase in s:
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

It always just prints no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An efficient way to check if some string `s` contains any character from some alphabet:

```
alphabet = frozenset(string.ascii_lowercase)
any(letter in alphabet for letter in s)
```

Key points:

- Avoid linear search by storing the alphabet in a set instead of a more general iterable that doesn't allow fast (O(1)) check of elements
- Loop over the input, not the target alphabet, because the alphabet is probably a finite set of constant size, and allow even very large inputs efficiently, without linear searching and excessive memory use (putting input in a set instead of the alphabet)
- Avoid unnecessary list creation (and wasted memory) by using a generator expression

Here are some inferior alternatives.

Linear search over `string.ascii_lowercase`:

```
any(letter in string.ascii_lowercase for letter in s)
```

Linear search over `string.ascii_lowercase`, and a useless list creation:

```
any([letter in string.ascii_lowercase for letter in s])
```

Linear search over the input, very poor performance in the worst case when the input is very long and does not contain any character from the alphabet:

```
any(letter in s for letter in string.ascii_lowercase)
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, `string.ascii_lowercase` is equal to `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`. That doesn't look like it's contained in `hello`, right?

What you should do instead is to go over the letters in `ascii_lowercase` and check if any of them are in your string s.

```
import string

s = ('hello')

if any([letter in s for letter in string.ascii_lowercase]):
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

Wonderfully smart people in the comments have pointed out that you can drop the `[ ]` brackets that would usually create a list, turning our list comprehension into something called a **generator**. This would prevent the need to check every single letter in `ascii_lowercase` and make our code a little bit faster - as it stands, the whole list is generated and then checked. With the generator, the letters are checked only up to `e`, as that's in `'hello'`.

I was able to shave off **a whole nanosecond** this way! Still, straight up going through the whole list should be fine as well for most cases and is certainly simpler.

Comment: If you remove the `[` brackets from inside `any`, you'll get a generator expression, which will allow the generator to quit early if appropriate.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh `any` quits early in either case, it's the computing of `letter in s` which may quit early for the generator.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on generators, gentlefolks! Added that in.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you are checking whether the whole string `string.ascii_lowercase` is in `s`.

You have to check every single character of `string.ascii_lowercase` instead.

The naive solution would look like this:

```
>>> s = 'hello'
>>> for letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
...     if letter in s:
...         print('yes')
...         break
... else:
...     print('no')
... 
yes
```

Here, the `else` block will only execute if the loop was not broken by the `break` statement.

A shorthand for the `for` loop would be to use the `any` builtin paired with a generator-expression:

```
>>> contained = any(letter in s for letter in string.ascii_lowercase)
>>> print('yes' if contained else 'no')
yes
```

Finally, you can improve the runtime of both implementations by using the `set` of characters from `s`, i.e. `s = set(s)`. This will ensure that every `in` check is performed in constant time rather than iterating over `s` for every letter that is searched.

edit: Here's another short one:

```
>>> if set(s).intersection(string.ascii_lowercase):
...     print('yes')
... else:
...     print('no')
... 
yes
```

This uses the fact that an empty set (the possible result of the intersection) will be treated as `False` in the `if` check.

(It has the slight drawback that the computation of the intersection does not stop once a single shared letter letter is found.)

Answer (score 0):

Make a `set` of each string and check the size of their intersection

```
def share_letter(s1, s2):
    return bool(set(s1).intersection(s2))
```

Comment: Use the `intersection` method, and there is no need to construct a set for the second argument: `set(s1).intersection(s2)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is another option:

```
import string

s = ('hello')
alpha = string.ascii_lowercase

if any(i in alpha for i in s):
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

Or maybe quicker:

```
import string

s = ('hello')
alpha = string.ascii_lowercase

for l in s:
    if l in alpha:
        print("yes")
        break
    print("no")
```

Answer (score 0):

`string.ascii_lowercase` is a string that contains all the lower case alphabets, i.e `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`.

So, in the if condition, `if string.ascii_lowercase in s` you are checking if the string contains a substring `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`.

You can try this,

```
if any(e in string.ascii_lowercase for e in s):
    ...
```

The expression inside `any` is a generator, thus it stop checking at the first match.

Another way to do this is,

```
if any(e.islower() for e in s):
    ...
```